# recording cpu usage of java applications

Tags: java, database, memory-management, rdbms, cpu-usage

At present I have a set of benchmark tests for recording the speed at which a Java application connects submits and returns data from varying RDBMS housed on varying server platforms. The application uses a simple algorithm for recording the time taken associated with each test. The application itself is a simple Java interface for a user to specify the tests, this seemed easier than hard coding each test or using an IDE to perform each test (bare in mind with the combination of RDBMS, Server O.S and client O.S there are in the region of several hundred individual tests). I would like to further my findings by introducing the cpu usage and memory usage during these tests on the client side where the application resides, I could hard code the algorithm for doing so in my application(My Preference) or use a third party software for monitoring this (Bare in mind it would need to be suitable for cross platform use, Windows 7, Solaris and Ubuntu).

So my question is how could I record the usage of CPU and Memory during a test through either hard coding in my Java application or Using a third party software? If you believe a third party would be the solution please could you mention the actual product and how it is possible to do this?

Thankyou to all who take the time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/). Has a lot of features

I used VisualVM and help to much to get memory leaks.

[Here](http://blip.tv/file/1582849) has a video who show most important VisualVM features

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of commercial products for this. JProbe is my favorite these days, but I'm also using YourKit. In the free arena, Eclipse has "TPTT" -- "Test Platform something something" -- but it seems to be a rare person who can actually get the darn thing to work. Never works for me.

Comment: haha thankyou for those I was really hoping to develop the application to include it within but this ceratinly helps. Thanks!